# Is there a network switch's brand which is more linux friendly than others?

Tags: networking

So basically I'm looking to set up a LAN of 3 to 8 PC (all running with ubuntu). The goal is to transfer lots of data between them.

I intended to buy a network switch and connect all the machines to it.

After some serious issues with a network adapter which was not linux friendly (now I know that Intel is more suitable), I'm checking before purchasing this other piece of equipment.

PS : I think that any switch will do since it is not OS dependent... but as a newbie, I'm still asking.

PS2 : it appears that setting up a static network is quite easy, but if you got a good tuto I'll take a look at it.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be more concerned with the bandwidth than the manufacturer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network switches really don't care what they are connected to.  All LAN devices follow well defined standards so you can connect Network printers, XBox, PS3 and computers running any OS without worry.

I have a wide range of hardware, from embedded systems to PCs running multiple OS's on my networks both at home and at work and it all just works.